# Clone html element not inheriting it properties

Tags: jquery, html, combobox, clone

I'm cloning a select/combobox, but I don't want to clone it value or properties or behaviors, just an empty combobox with the same options available.

What is happening is that it is cloning the value too.

Can you show me a litle working example ?

I'm using jQuery.

I know you may ask for my code, but is a bit long to show it here because I'm using a 3rd party plugin which works with tables and cloning rows.

Comment: Ill try to setup a fiddle then

Comment: `clone()` will clone the value as well, but all you have to do is remove the value. `$(element).clone().val('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the selected value of the cloned `select` to that of the original `select`:

```
var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
    clone = $(this).clone().appendTo('body');
$(clone).val(selected);
```

Here's a crude [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrhCP/).

You'll probably want to call `.appendTo()` *after* setting the selected value, however (`$(clone).appendTo(...);`).

**Edit:** Seems I may have misread your question. Chrome [*doesn't* copy over the selected value](http://jsfiddle.net/BrhCP/2/) on `clone`. To unset the value, you'd simply:

```
$(clone).val(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(element).clone();`

little example could be:

```
<div id="lol">lol</div>

$(function(){
$('#lol').append($('#lol').clone());
});
```

if you want to clone only the html tags just do:

```
<div id="lol">lol</div>

    $(function(){
    $('#lol').append($('#lol').clone().html("").text(""));
    });
```

Comment: Does it clone the value of element too ?

Comment: @skdnewbie it clones all, the element is an object, so it clones the object at all, values,markup all :D

Comment: Ye :x My prob is that. For my purpose I just want to clone the element without it value. It is impossible?

Comment: @skdnewbie can you define *value* please? do you want only the html tags of the element? and check my latest example in answer ;)